# Why can't I remove Apache?

Tags: web-server, apt, apache-httpd

I installed a LAMP stack with the following commands:

```
$sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
$sudo service apache2 restart
$sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

*[Full instructions](http://www.element14.com/community/community/raspberry-pi/raspberrypi_projects/blog/2014/02/24/raspberry-pi-as-a-lamp-server)*.

Anyway, I found that Apache isn't the most lightweight server out there, and I found Nginx. So, naturally, I tried uninstalling Apache:

```
$sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

I even tried stopping the service before and rebooting afterwards. It goes through the remove process fine, but the service stays there. If I run that command again, it will say that Apache is uninstalled. I've tried uninstalling all of these packages: `apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5`, but, whenever I reboot and go to my Pi's IP, I always get the Apache welcome file.

I then thought that it would be an issue of another web server was handling the Apache file. However, I can still stop the page from loading with `sudo service apache2 stop`. Why is this happening/how can I fix this?

Comment: should have used `remove` command instead of `purge`

Comment: @lenik That doesn't seem to be true. From the `man apt-get` page: *purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too).* Why would removing the configuration files not uninstall a package? Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Are you sure Apache is serving the Apache welcome HTML?  Perhaps your new web server is.

Comment: @joan read the last paragraph

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get --purge remove apache2` and then `sudo apt-get autoremove`. I had that same thing with emacs due to it installing other dependencies. emacs would still be there after --purge remove. Autoremove helped removing the dependencies which were installed with emacs.

Comment: Worked! I also had to remove these packages before the autoremove: `mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql`.

Answer (score -2):

If these commands don't work:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
$ sudo service apache2 restart
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php5-mysql
```

Try this:

```
$ sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php
$ sudo service apache2 restart
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client php-mysql
```

Comment: This does not seem to be an answer to the question.